# Procedural Chrono Trigger portal

Tags: shaders, procedural, texture-coordinates

I'm working on a project and I stumbled upon a problem, to make things short, I have to make a procedural [portal with the Chrono Trigger style](https://lparchive.org/Chrono-Trigger-(by-Mega64)/Update%2004/171-231.gif).

[image: Example of the portal]

My approach was using a wave texture with polar coordinates to achieve that effect where lines merge with others and split apart again. But it doesn't come close.

[image: The shader I have right now]

[image: My current nodetree]

The main problem is probably the texture coordinates, I know it must be polar coordinates, but it has to be offset so it's not only converging lines in the middle, like a secondary center point, preferably multiple.

Comment: Sadly, the method that they used to make the original effect in Chrono Trigger is basically no longer available on modern computers.  It only works in a 256 color graphics environment, by use of palette swapping.  (You'll notice that the pattern remains fixed, it's only the colors that rotate through the pattern.)  I used the technique quite a bit myself back in the day, but it can't be done that way in 24-bit graphics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's my try - There are several sections added together:

[image: Wavefull]

First start with a Normalized Object Texture Co-ordinate, offset by a mapping node. This will make the lines of the wave point towards the "center", but be offset like the reference image.

The next section uses the Distance output of a Voronoi texture node to make the "Vortex points" so to speak - more than one turbulent area.

[image: Wave1]

The next section "Warps" the lines slightly with a noise texture so they look more "flowing"

The section after that adds a pixilation look to the waves (optional, depending on how low-fi you're going for).

[image: Wave2]

This all goes into a wave texture, that is then "Quantized" by using several *constant* steps in a ColorRamp for the colors.

[image: Wave3]

Lastly, there is a "Movement" Section (if you plan on animating), I used a value node to control the location of a Mapping Node connected to the input of the Voronoi texture. I used a math node to slow it down a little. If you want this to move as you animate, type #frame into the Value box.

[image: Wave4]

[image: Warp]

(actual animation looks quite a lot better - I had to cut it way down to meet upload file-size requirements)

Comment: Ah this is awesome

Answer (score 4):

I had to give this one a shot since it's one of my favorite games.

My solution is far from complete and comes down to masking and messing around with different *MixRGB* settings.  *Screen* and *Soft Light* both gave interesting results.

[image]

Animate the Value node to see the motion.

Comment: wave texture scale is set to pi

Comment: Looks good.... still trying to re-create the graph to try it out.